# How to initialize {[key: string]: string} to {} in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```
interface a {
    d: {[key: string]: string}
}

class a {
    d = {}
}
```

returns the following error :

> Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'd' must be of type '{ [key: string]: string; }', but here has type '{}'.

```
let v: {[key: string]: string} = {}
```

is accepted without warning/error

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface and class have the same name - `a`. Rename one of them to something else. What you are looking for is probably something like this:

```
class b implements a {
    d = {}
}
```

Comment: Maybe a link to the documentation about TS interfaces might be a nice thing to add? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html